# Protractor excel4node doesn't work

Tags: javascript, excel, protractor

I'm trying to save some data into my excel:

```
var xl = require('excel4node');
var wb = new xl.Workbook();
var ws = wb.addWorksheet('abc1');
ws.cell(1,1).string('abc2');
ws.cell(1,2).string('abc3');
ws.cell(1,3).string('abc4');
ws.cell(1,4).string('abc5');
```

It works fine but when i am trying to:

```
var a = element(by.className('token')).getText();
ws.cell(2,8).string(a);
```

I get an error:

> Failed: val.match is not a function

I know that "a" return a good string value, because I've checked the logs.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? It seems like we're missing some details.

Comment: Just edited the question. Note that I've added more relevant tags (more people can find the question and help potentially).